# applications of topology or abstract algebra to astronomy

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, applications

That is my question, there are applications of the branch of topology or abstract algebra to the astronomy? I know that there are to physics but to astronomy?

Comment: This might be better suited for http://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If there are applications of physics to astronomy, by transitivity...

Comment: Yes, there are - for example, see a similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/474884/

Answer (score 2):

The whole area of qualitative dynamical systems, which contains plenty of topology, was inaugurated by [Poincaré](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Poincar%C3%A9#Astronomy_and_celestial_mechanics) to answer questions in celestial mechanics. (I hope this counts as astronomy.)