# Graph (or Group) in Astronomy

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, applications

Is there an application of graph theory (or group theory) in astronomy. If there is, refer me some references.

Comment: A distant recollection from the two courses in theoretical mechanics is that conservation laws in physics are manifestations of underlying symmetry groups: rotational invariance => conservation of angular momentum, invariance under translations => conservation of momentum, invariance under temporal translation => conservation of energy. I believe such conservation laws are ubiquitous in astronomy.

Comment: @Jyrki: You're thinking of [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).

Comment: The constellations on the star sky maps are drawn as typical graphs. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The GAP homepage recently got new sections where the GAP bibliography may be browsed [by year](http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Bib/Year/year.html) and [by MSC2010 subjects](http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Bib/MSC/msc.html).

It happens that there is one publication using GAP in the category ["Mechanics of particles and systems"](http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Bib/MSC/70.html). Secondary MSC codes and the list of citations point that it is relevant to celestial mechanics:

- Ferrario, D. L. and Terracini, S., On the existence of collisionless equivariant minimizers for the classical $n$-body problem, Invent. Math., 155 (2) (2004), 305--362.
- See also the preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0302022v3

Comment: Nice hints like a milky way at night:-) +1